# GWT user.agent for Hosted Mode?

Tags: gwt, maven, gxt

As far as I know the "user.agent" property in the Google Web Toolkit .gwt.xml file specifies the targets for the Java to Java Script translation. Because the hosted mode still runs Java and not Javascript I don't understand why google chrome complains that the "user.agent" value is not set correctly. Even more strange, it keeps complaining even if I add "safari" to it with `<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8,safari" />`.

What can I do here?

I use GWT version 2.3.0 and GXT version  2.2.5.

Answer (score 3):

DevMode does not compile to JavaScript but still has to honor deferred binding rules, and many of them are based on the `user.agent` property, so it must be correctly set.

The `user.agent` property value is determined by some script snippet generated in the so-called *selection script* (the `*.nocache.js` file), and the content of this script can depend on the `set-property`s you have in your GWT module(s).

For instance, if you compile a GWT module with `<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" />`, the `user.agent` property will be hard-coded to the `gecko1_8` value in the `*.nocache.js`.
If you later run DevMode, unless it thinks it has to overwrite the existing `*.nocache.js`, it'll use it; so running the app using Chrome when the `*.nocache.js` was generated for `gecko1_8` only will cause an error similar to:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Property 'user.agent' of object  is not a function
```

In case you compiled for several browsers, but then run DevMode with a module only for `gecko1_8`, then the DevMode will use the property provider found in the `*.nocache.js` to determine the *actual* user agent being used (woul dbe `safari` for Chrome), and will compare it with the one determined from the module (hard-coded here to `gecko1_8`), and will then warn you that they don't match (and as such that you app might dysfunction: the code will use `DOMImplMozilla` for instance, whereas `DOMImplSafari` should have been used in Chrome).

---

So, to fix this, either delete the `*.nocache.js` file so DevMode will have to generate a new one, or recompile your app with a module whose `user.agent` values match the browser you'll use in DevMode.